# Dual-boot Bluetooth with LE QC35II headphones on Windows / Linux inconsistent or not working

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, multi-boot, bluetooth

I've been having a terrible time connecting my Bose QC35II (LE) to Windows 11 when I also have a Linux Mint partition on a separate M.2 drive for months. It was the same story on Windows 10, Debian/Arch.

The Linux connection works fine, I just disconnect and reconnect the headphones and it works. The issue is on Windows, it takes me forever to reconnect my headphones. I uninstall every Bluetooth device driver under device manager - Microsoft Bluetooth enumerator, Bose QC35 II drivers, everything. Unplug my Bluetooth dongle, plug it back in. I reset the headphones, unpair all devices, even factory reset. It doesn't help, its some quirk with windows that's causing me problems. And it only happens when I also have my M.2 with Linux plugged into my motherboard.

When I search for devices, it often shows LE-Bose QC35II but connecting to it doesn't do anything and I can easily remove it. The non LE version, Bose QC35II, remains in the "not connected" menu (I can't post images with my rep), and I can't remove it no matter what I disable or remove in the device manager. Removing it always fails which seems to be part of the issue.

Getting the headphones to connect on windows seems like luck, but as soon as Bose QC35II appear as a device I can connect to, it works, but getting to that point is random. Sometimes I just have to reseat my dongle and I can connect. Sometimes it's an hour of uninstalling Bluetooth drivers and it miraculously works.

I don't care about auto-connecting or anything special, I don't mind having to go through a few steps to reconnect every boot. I just want a reliable set of steps to connect when I boot into windows. Completely disabling the LE-hands free portion of the headphones so I don't have to "disallow" them as input every time I connect them would be a nice bonus.

I'd at least like some advice on how to debug this issue. Internally, how does windows search for Bluetooth devices, and what could cause my headphones not being "connectable"?

I've read through [every line of the dual-boot Arch Linux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth#Dual_boot_pairing). I got the MAC address and set the Linux bluez [LinkKey] to use that mac address. I've read every post I could find on superuser + stack-exchange + unix forums. None of them solve this issue.